# Fail with generating JSONP in Slim PHP , can't read it in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I'm trying to make some Web project including communication between AngularJS in front-end and SlimPHP in back-end.

I want to invoke query in php script and generate JSON object to work with it in my front-end MVC

This is part of my php script , using Slim PHP framework

```
$app->get('/users','getUsers');


$app->run();

// GET http://www.yourwebsite.com/api/users
function getUsers() {
$sql = "SELECT user_id,username,name,profile_pic FROM users ORDER BY user_id DESC";
try {
    $db = getDB();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
 echo  json_encode($users);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
//error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/phperror.log'); //Write error log
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
}
```

In my controller in Angular this expression just doesn't work correctly

```
 $http.jsonp("localhost/users).success(function (data) {
            $scope.myusers = data.results;

        }
    )
```

What should I change in my php script ? In the browser everything looks correctly when i type http://localhost/users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$http.jsonp()` which is only used for cross domain `json with padding` requests. These are not regular ajax requests they are actually script requests that require a special outer wrapper function call.

For normal json GET requests use `$http.get()`

```
$http.get("localhost/users").success(function (data) {
        $scope.myusers = data.results;
});
```

Comment: When I type 
  http://localhost/api/libs/index.php/users
In my browser I get as result
 [{"user_id":"1","username":"Maciej","name":"Ciach","profile_pic":"adsfasfdasf"}]

But Angular still doesn't get it ;c

Comment: inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network (F12). You can see what is sent/returned, status, errors etc

Comment: OHHH... remove `'localhost` ...without `http://localhost` it is a relative url ... `$http.get("/users")`